# Distinguish between Algebras

Tags: measure-theory

$$ S_n = \mathscr P (\{ -n, -n+1, \ldots, n-1, n\}) $$
$$ R_n = \{r : \Omega - r \in S_n\} $$ 
$$ T_n = S_n \cup R_n$$

I need to check whether

1. $T_n$ is an algebra, semi-algebra or sigma algebra.
2. $T_n \subset T_{n+1}$.
3. If  $T = \bigcup_n  T_n$, whether $T$ is algebra, semi-algebra, sigma algebra.

I considered an example for this:

Let $ S_1 = \mathscr P \{-1, 0, 1\} $
$$ S_1 = \{\{-1\}, \{0\}, \{1\} ,\{-1,0\}, \{0,1\}, \{-1,1\}, \{-1,0,1\},\{ \varnothing\}\}$$

So, for 1) I feel that $T_n = \Omega$, so it can either be any of the algebras.

Please advise.

Comment: Which part of the definitions are you having trouble checking?

Comment: Still, I want to check my idea for 1) is correct.

Comment: What is $\Omega$?  Is it $\mathbb{Z}$?  And do you mean that $T_n = \mathscr{P}(\Omega)$ for all $n$?  If so, why?

Comment: Does what $\Omega$ is matter here? Since $T_n = S_n \cup R_n$ doesn't $T_n$ automatically becomes $\Omega$.

Comment: I think you may be confused about what the definitions in the problem mean.  The symbol $\mathscr{P}$ means "power set," so for example $S_1$ consists of all eight subsets of the set $\{-1,0,1\}$.

Comment: ...and $R_n$ is the set of complements of elements of $S_n$, which is not the same as the complement of $S_n$ itself.

Comment: Yeah, I have edited the problem to include that example. So R becomes the complement sets of S. So when we take their union again...doesn't that make up to $\Omega$ again. I am confused!

Comment: $S_n$ and $R_n$ both consist of subsets of $\Omega$, not elements of $\Omega$.  Their union $T_n$ also consists of subsets of $\Omega$, not elements of $\Omega$.  Maybe if you write down some of the elements of $R_1$ it will become clearer.

Answer (score 1):

1. $T_n$ is stable by complementation (almost by definition) and by intersections: if $A, B\in T_n$ and $A,B\in S_n$ then $A\cap B\in S_n$, if $A,B\in R_n$ then $A\cap B\in R_n$ and if $A\in R_n$ and $B\in S_n$ then $A\cap B=\emptyset$. So $T_n$ is a semi-algebra and since $\Omega\in T_n$, an algebra. $T_n$ is a $\sigma$-algebra as a *finite* algebra.
2. Since $S_n\subset S_{n+1}$, if $A\in T_n$, either $A\in S_n$, then $A\in S_{n+1}\subset T_{n+1}$ or $A\in R_n$, then $\Omega\setminus A\in S_n\subset S_{n+1}$ hence $A\in T_{n+1}$, which proves inclusion.
3. An increasing sequence of (semi-)algebras is a (semi-)algebra so $T$ is a (semi-)algebra. It's not a $\sigma$-algebra as $\{2k,k\in\Bbb Z\}$ is a countable union  of elements of $T$ but not an element of $T$.